# Make in parallel

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

In this project, a top level rule looks like this:

```
all:
        for l in $(LIBDIRS); do $(MAKE) -C $$l all; done
```

If I run `make -jx`, the files in each directory are compiled in parallel, but because of this bash loop, make doesn't move onto files in the next library until everything is done in the current one. What's the best way to change the loop so that it call truly be done in parallel? I only use gnumake, so gnu extensions are fine.

*** Edit *** as an aside, I was trying something like this

```
ALL_DEPENDENCY = $(foreach l, $(LIBDIRS), $(l).PHONY_LIB_RULE)
.PHONY: $(ALL_DEPENDENCY)
%.PHONY_LIB_RULE:
        $(MAKE) --no-print-directory -C $(patsubst %.PHONY_LIB_RULE,%,$@) all

all: $(ALL_DEPENDENCY)
```

but these rules aren't tripped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check this answer for an example of how to do this more correctly: [makefile: foreach "make -C" call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15661951/makefile-foreach-make-c-call/15664207)

Comment: I looked at your answer, and it seems the second thing you suggest is what I was already trying (see my edit), so I clearly have some subtlety wrong. Do you see what it is?

Comment: Indeed, I just got rid of the PHONY_LIB_RULE bit and used your solution exactly, and that works. Thanks